# how are javascript object variables stored?

Tags: javascript

I tried to understand this plugin system but got a little confused.

```
var obj={};
obj.plugin={
create: function(pluginname){
    var default_value='p1';
    var f1 = function(){
            alert(default_value);
            //define plugin properties
        }
    obj[pluginname] = function(){return new f1();}
    /*
    run other code here
    */
    return {
        //
        f2: function(args){
            default_value=args;
        }                    
    }
}
};
obj.plugin.create('pluginA').f2('pa');
obj.plugin.create('pluginB').f2('pb');
obj.pluginA();  // pa
obj.pluginB();  // pb
```

I think the result should be like this:

```
obj.pluginA();  // pb
obj.pluginB();  // pb
```

And another question is : 'new f1()' will not be run until the last two line. where the 'default_value' has been stored?

Comment: Object is like a folder where it can contains subfolders and files. i.e.: simple variable types and/or subobjects.

Answer (score 0):

A little source code explanation first:

```
var obj={};
obj.plugin={
// object plugin property is an object that has create property defined here
// create property is a function that adds another properties to object in general
create: function(pluginname){
    // this default value has got 'var' modifier - it is local and has scope of 'create'
    var default_value='p1';
    // f1 is a plugin's function - it does what a plugin creator implements
    var f1 = function(){
            // it encloses 'default_value' locally in 'create'
            alert(default_value);
            //define plugin properties
        }
    // the line below is the creation of a new property, which allows the object
    // to call a method of name of a plugin; it assigns to the property of that name
    // the f1 function closure, but local to actual execution of 'create';
    // note the use of 'new' operator which copies the function making it independent
    // from other calls of 'create'
    obj[pluginname] = function(){return new f1();}
    /*
    run other code here
    */
    return {
        // this function allows you to change 'default_value' still in scope
        // of the same call of 'create', thus effectively changing that one (locally - it's 'var');
        f2: function(args){
            default_value=args;
        }                    
    }
// after leaving this brace you leave the 'create' scope
}
// and the plugin object scope
};
```

Now how it'll work:

This: `obj.plugin.create('pluginA').f2('pa');`
asks plugin property for `create`, which is a function, which is called with `'pluginA'` string. **To call that function js creates the context of the call** (which in fact is some structured object on top of the stack). `'pluginA'` is put on the stack as an argument, `default_value`, `f1` and `f2` are put on the stack as a local variables. Then `create` function is executed. Initialization of variables goes first, then this assignment
`obj[pluginname] = function(){return new f1();}`

This creates `pluginA` property in object. Notice, that then the local function f1 is passed outside the scope, to the global `object` as a property. Then there is a `return` statement which pops all local variables, and all actual parameters from the stack and puts in returning value which escapes the call scope. Then the scope is left.

Here a little trick takes place. The returned value is an object that has got a function having a reference to 'default_value' from the scope that has been left. It is possible, because, in fact, actual objects are stored on the heap, while on the stack there are only references to those. It means that `default_value` still exists on the heap and is referenced by `f2` function in that returned object.

When `f2` is called the control enters `f2` call scope. Since it's been defined in `create` it has reference to the `default value` object on the heap. Since it can access that object, it can also change it - to `'pa'`. Then `f2`'s call scope is left, and after the semicolon the returned value is also left. The `f1` function also has the reference to that `default_value`, now equal to `'pa'`. That `f1` function is 'closed' in `'pluginA'` property of an `object`.

It means, that a global `object` now has got a property `pluginA`, that is a function (that were named `f1`). That function has a reference to an object (that were named `default_value`). And that object is a string `'pa'`. **The values are kept accessible via indirect reference in always accessible `object`.**

This: `obj.plugin.create('pluginB').f2('pb');`
does the same thing respectively with other parameters, hence creates `pluginB` property in object. It is another call of `create`, so it has got a totally new `default_value`. That is another local instance. The very same magic closes that new object in global `object` in another property (pluginB). `Create` returns a new object that encloses a new function `f2`. That one is has access to that 'newer' `default_value`, but has nothing to do with the one from the previous call. When `f2` is called on another returned object it changes that "new" `default_value` to `'pb'`.

After that, the below is self-explanatory...

```
obj.pluginA();  // pa
obj.pluginB();  // pb
```

Comment: I got you but i can't understand how js worked in memory. T_T

Comment: To understand the whole, you need to first understand the part. What is that concerns you most? Point that out, so I could know where do you need detailed explanation.

Comment: You say "After the semicolon, create's call scope is left",but i can't see "create's call scope" through firebug or Chrome tool.I just want to know how it exist.